# NSLocalization + Storyboard using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, autolayout, nslocalizedstring

So this is very strange:

I created a small UIView in Storyboard, changed its color so we can see it.
I also created a button so I can make this view bigger.

What happens is it only works if I don't access NSLocalizedString. If I decomment the line it stops working.

Why is this?

```
class MasterViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var bar: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    var integer : Int = 0

    @IBAction func makeBarGrow(sender : AnyObject) {
        self.integer++
       //self.button.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("test \(integer)", comment : "test"), forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        self.bar.frame = CGRectMake(self.bar.frame.origin.x,
            self.bar.frame.origin.y,
            self.bar.frame.size.width + 10,
            self.bar.frame.size.height)
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm incrementing integer so it accesses NSLocalizedString everytime. Otherwise it will work from the second time on

Comment: what do you mean by "stops working"?

Comment: @BryanChen what I meant is that the code above works (changes the frame of self.bar) unless I uncomment the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the label on your button, Auto Layout runs and sets the frame of your bar back to its initial value.  When Auto Layout is enabled, you shouldn't adjust frame sizes.  Instead, you should use size constraints like so:

1. Add an Auto Layout constraint on your bar that sets its width. To do this, select your bar view in *Interface Builder* and click the Auto Layout Pin icon <kbd>|-[]-|</kbd>, click the box next to *Width*, and set the constant to your desired initial value.  Then click <kbd>Add 1 Constraint</kbd> at the bottom.
2. Add an IBOutlet to this constraint in your ViewController by <kbd>Control</kbd> dragging from the constraint in the *Document Layout View* to your code:

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var barWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
   ```
3. In `makeBarGrow`, replace `frame` adjusting code with:

   ```
   barWidth.constant += 10
   ```

Comment: Auto Layout runs when you update the label on your button and sets your frame back to the default.  When Auto Layout is on, you shouldn't set or adjust frames, you should set constraints on width like I showed above.  I'd appreciate an up vote as well if you'd be so inclined.  Thanks.